# How can I stop "clipboard hijacking" globally?

Tags: javascript, web, clipboard, spam-prevention

This is getting to be a real bugbear of mine, and from what I understand it's becoming more common.

A few of you might have heard of *Tynt*, a site that offers clipboard-hijacking services. With their API on your site, users that copy your content will either have the content they copy altered or a link to the website they sourced the information from will be placed at the end.

I object on a fundamental level to allowing anyone but myself access over my clipboard. It's a personal aspect of the computer and not one I plan on letting marketers into.

Previously, blocking clipboard hijacking was easy because Tynt were the only ones trying it, so setting up a hosts redirect for *tcr.tynt.com* killed it all without issue. Now, however, I see that other sites are hosting their own imitations, which do much the same thing.

Here's a JavaScript applet from one such site: http://www.lyricsmania.com/copy.js

You can test it out yourself by looking at any page of theirs: http://www.lyricsmania.com/watershed_lyrics_mark_hollis.html and copying any of the lyrics from there. They will add a link to their own site and a spam link beneath it.

Is it possible to instruct Google Chrome to block all scripts of this specific type? Is there a way to blanket deny pamphleteers access to my clipboard? I'd love to hear what anyone thinks.

I could use [NoScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript), but unless I'm mistaken, it doesn't contain any intelligent code to recognise JavaScript that's trying to hijack my clipboard, so it's not particularly useful here.

Comment: techie007, this looks very similar to my query. thanks! my search didn't use the right terms to pick this question up so i appreciate it.

Comment: @seagull Might I also suggest you try http://someonewhocares.org/hosts/ as the hosts file there is updated quite regularly and seems to block most hijacking sites such as Tynt.

Answer (score 3):

I found an extension that blocks this BS conclusively.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kill-evil/epieehnpcepgfiildhdklacomihpoldk/related

It's called "kill evil".

Comment: The link is broken (404).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Looks like evil was stronger. Many such cases.